# Grouping items inside TListView object?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am trying to group the items inside TListView object, but I cant find the class responsible for grouping the objects, neither i were able to find such inside the documentation.

- What is the class responsible about grouping items inside TListView object, and how to use it properly ?

*The platform is Firemonkey ( Android/iOS) / Delphi XE6*

Comment: AFAIK, grouping is a feature specific for the VCL Windows Listview, and this is not available in the FMX Listview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The property I believe you're referring to is `TListGroups`, a collection that holds `TListGroup` items. There's a [demo](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/ListGroups_%28Delphi%29) provided in the Delphi documentation.

Unfortunately, it's only available in the VCL and not FMX, as the underlying functionality is part of the Windows ListView control that `TListView` wraps.

The closest you can get in FMX is using `TListBox` and a `TListBoxGroupHeader`, which is covered in the Multi-Device Tutorial *Using ListBox Components to Display a Table View (iOS and Android)* in the [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3A_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_%28iOS_and_Android%29):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  c: Char;
  i: Integer;
  Buffer: String;
  ListBoxItem : TListBoxItem;
  ListBoxGroupHeader : TListBoxGroupHeader;
begin
  ListBox1.BeginUpdate;
  for c := 'a' to 'z' do
  begin
    // Add header ('A' to 'Z') to the List
    ListBoxGroupHeader := TListBoxGroupHeader.Create(ListBox1);
    ListBoxGroupHeader.Text := UpperCase(c);
    ListBox1.AddObject(ListBoxGroupHeader);

    // Add items ('a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'b', 'bb', 'bbb', 'c', ...) to the list
    for i := 1 to 3 do
    begin
      // StringOfChar returns a string with a specified number of repeating characters.
      Buffer := StringOfChar(c, i);
      // Simply add item
      // ListBox1.Items.Add(Buffer);

      // or, you can add items by creating an instance of TListBoxItem by yourself
      ListBoxItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
      ListBoxItem.Text := Buffer;
      // (aNone=0, aMore=1, aDetail=2, aCheckmark=3)
      ListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory(i);
      ListBox1.AddObject(ListBoxItem);
    end;
  end;
  ListBox1.EndUpdate;
end;
```

This produces (image from the indicated docwiki)

[image: Sample table view listbox appearance in iOS and Android]

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished in FMX TListview control while using Livebindings by connecting your TListviewItem.header.break field to the fieled you want to group on (it will be a field in your db that is redundant over many records).